# I would like to turn a string (that should basically be a list of dictionaries) to a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, dictionary

I have a DataFrame named `df_imdb`, it has a column named genres, for example, if I
retrieve one of the rows like this:

```
df_imdb.loc[3000,'genres']
```

the answer would be:

```
[{'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}, {'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 9648, 'name': 'Mystery'}]
```

that is a string, but how could I convert it to an actual list?

Comment: What is the *source of this string*, you should avoid ever having to deal with this *in the first place*, but essentially, you want to `eval` it, or use `ast.literal_eval` if this is from untrusted input (e.g. user input)

Comment: The source is one of the columns of a DataFrame that should contain the Genre of some movies. each row is a list of dictionaries.

Comment: That's not what I mean. I mean **why** are these strings being generated? `"[{'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}, {'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 9648, 'name': 'Mystery'}]"` didn't just randomly come about.

Comment: No, it is very important for you to understand **it is not a list of dictionaries**. It is a **string**. Very important to understand that. That is the fundamental issue, something is creating a string which happens to represent a list of dictionaries instead of a list of dictionaries. That is the fundamental problem you should solve. Other approaches are just putting hacks on top of it, but if that's the way you want to go, again, `eval` or `ast.literal_eval`. But the real problem you should be solving is why that string exists in the first place

Comment: I have a DataFrame named df_imdb, it has a column named genres, for example, if I retrieve one of the rows like this: 

df_imdb.loc[3000,'genres'],

the answer would be:

"[{'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}, {'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 9648, 'name': 'Mystery'}]",

that is a String

Comment: Yes, I *understand that*. My point is that you shouldn't have those strings *to begin with*.  But using `eval` will let you hack around your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import ast

s = "[{'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}, {'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 9648, 'name': 'Mystery'}]"
x = ast.literal_eval(s)
```

`x` will be `[{'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}, {'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 9648, 'name': 'Mystery'}]`.
so printing, for example, `x[0]['id']` will show you `53`

Comment: This works if the string only consists of literals, otherwise you need to use `eval()`